# JavaScript ISO 8601 string into Date object

Tags: javascript, parsing, datetime, timezone, iso8601

Consider the following two snippets in a browser's JavaScript console (I have tried with Google Chrome)

1st Statement:

```
s = "2014-03-03 18:30:00";
d = new Date(s);
// Mon Mar 03 2014 18:30:00 GMT+0100 (CET)
```

2nd Statement:

```
s = "2014-03-03T18:30:00";
d = new Date(s);
// Mon Mar 03 2014 19:30:00 GMT+0100 (CET)
```

See? The parsed date and time differs with one hour for me, as I live in UTC+1.

But why does the JavaScript Date object parse these two strings differently, for there is no time zone given at all?

Comment: The 1st one is parsed as local time, the 2nd as UTC.  When you the `T` in the 2nd example, that means you are specifying a time and a time zone.  Since you *don't* give it a timezone, it assumes it as `0` (UTC).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- The `2014-03-03T...` notation is a fancy [JavaScript Date Time String Format](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.1.15) and expects a time zone. If you don't provide one, it defaults to `Z` (UTC).
- The `2014-03-03 18:30:00` notation, however, is just a regular string without an interesting name and, if you don't provide a time zone, it assumes local time.

This info was taken from the [MDN article about `Date.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse).